# Kruskal-Wallis test for multiple variables different in R and python

Tags: r, python, inference, kruskal-wallis-test

My dataset has one athlete per observation, and each column is the points he obtained in each category. I want to test if the medians for all the categories (so, the median of each column) are the same. I first started my analysis on Python and what I did was:

```
kruskal(best5p['prop_100m'], best5p['prop_400m'], best5p['prop_110h'], best5p['prop_1500m'],
best5p['prop_sp'], best5p['prop_hj'], best5p['prop_lj'], best5p['prop_jav'], best5p['prop_disc'], best5p['prop_pv'])

Out[23]: KruskalResult(statistic=2377.172528453154, pvalue=0.0)
```

I tried doing the same on R and this is the result:

```
kruskal.test(best$prop_100m, best$prop_400m, best$prop_110h, best$prop_1500m, best$prop_sp, best$prop_hj, best$prop_lj, best$prop_jav, best$prop_disc, best$prop_pv)

Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  best$prop_100m and best$prop_400m
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 398.61, df = 398, p-value = 0.4819
```

As you can see, R is clearly grabbing only the first two variables.

I tried coding it another way and it gives me an error:

```
kruskal.test(best$prop_100m ~ best$prop_400m + best$prop_110h + best$prop_1500m + best$prop_sp + best$prop_hj + best$prop_lj + best$prop_jav + best$prop_disc + best$prop_pv)

Error in kruskal.test.formula(best$prop_100m ~ best$prop_400m + best$prop_110h + : 'formula' should be of the form response ~ group
Traceback:

1. kruskal.test(best$prop_100m ~ best$prop_400m + best$prop_110h + 
 .     best$prop_1500m + best$prop_sp + best$prop_hj + best$prop_lj + 
 .     best$prop_jav + best$prop_disc + best$prop_pv)
2. kruskal.test.formula(best$prop_100m ~ best$prop_400m + best$prop_110h + 
 .     best$prop_1500m + best$prop_sp + best$prop_hj + best$prop_lj + 
 .     best$prop_jav + best$prop_disc + best$prop_pv)
3. stop("'formula' should be of the form response ~ group")
```

Is python really doing what I think it is (i.e. comparing the medians of each variable)? 
Is there a way to get R to do what I want to do?

Comment: You should try reading the documentation for the R `kruskal.test` function instead of assuming it works just like the python `kruskal` function.   If the documentation isn't clear enough, the example included in the documentation should be.

Comment: @jbowman I checked and I see no trace of anything related to more than 1 independent variable on the R documentation... this means it is not possible to do so on R then? I am very new in R and quite new in Python, I thought the same test would have the "same" arguments for python and R

Comment: @jbowman nevermind, realized the answer was indeed in one part of the example on the documentarion

Comment: I was just about to try to explain the example, so good on you for figuring it out!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has already been answered in the comments.